# Why is_wp_error() is not returning false even there's no defined error

Tags: comments, errors, wp-error

On the form submission I'm taking user comment for a custom purpose for my plugin. I'm checking whether the comment field is empty or not, and the comment field is filled with at least 30 characters. If both are ok, I want to insert the comment.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
global $current_user, $post;

if( isset( $_POST['send'] ) && isset( $_POST['test_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['test_nonce'], 'testify_nonce' ) ) {
    //global $error;
    $error = new WP_Error();

    $comment_content = $_POST['comment_content'];

    if( empty( $comment_content ) ) {
        $error->add( 'comment_empty', __("Comment field can't be empty.") );
    }
    if ( strlen( $comment_content ) < 30 ) {
        $error->add( 'comment_short', __("Your comment is too short. Write down at least 30 characters.") );
    }

    //test test test
    var_dump($error);
    if( is_wp_error( $error ) ) { echo 1; }
    //test test test

    if( is_wp_error( $error ) ) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
            echo $error->get_error_message();
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        $commentdata = array(
            'comment_post_ID'       => $post->ID,
            'comment_author'        => $current_user->display_name, 
            'comment_author_email'  => $current_user->user_email,
            'comment_author_url'    => $current_user->user_url,
            'comment_content'       => htmlentities( $comment_content ),
            'comment_type'          => '',
            'comment_parent'        => 0,
            'user_id'               => $current_user->ID,
            'comment_approved'      => '1' //approve by default
        );

        //Insert new comment and get the comment ID
        $comment_id = wp_insert_comment( $commentdata );

        if( ! is_wp_error( $comment_id ) ) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
                _e( 'Your comment is successfully submitted.', 'text-domain' );
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
                echo $comment_id->get_error_message();
            echo '</div>';
        } //endif( ! is_wp_error( $comment_id ) )
    } //endif( is_wp_error( $error ) )        
} //endif( $_POST['send'] )
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="comment_content" id="" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'testify_nonce', 'test_nonce' ); ?>
    <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary"><?php _e( 'Submit', 'text-domain' ); ?></button>
</form>
```

But on submission of the form, if I `var_dump( $error );`:

```
object(WP_Error)[398]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'error_data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

it's empty, but still the `if( is_wp_error( $error ) ) { echo 1; }` is showing `1`. And that's why the comment is not inserting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `is_wp_error` checks if the given var is an instance of `WP_Error` class ([source code as WP 4.2.2](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php#L217)):

```
function is_wp_error( $thing ) {
    return ( $thing instanceof WP_Error );
}
```

As you can see, if the given variable is a instance of WP_Error class, the function returns true, even if the object is empty. Your `$error` variable is a `WP_Error` instance, empty but a `WP_Error` instance, so it returns true. You could do something:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $error ) && ! empty( $error->errors ) )
```

Or initiate `WP_Error` only on certains conditions (write here, not tested):

```
$errors = array();

if ( empty( $comment_content ) ) {
    $errors['comment_empty'] = esc_html__("Comment field can't be empty.");
}
if ( strlen( $comment_content ) < 30 ) {
    $errors['comment_short'] = esc_html__("Your comment is too short. Write down at least 30 characters.");
}

if( ! empty( $errors ) ) {

    $wp_error = new WP_Error();
    foreach ( $errors as $code => $message ) {
        $wp_error->add( $code, $message );
    }

}

if ( is_wp_error( $wp_error ) ) {
}
```